# iOS custom keyboard throws error

Tags: ios

I have created an empty app and added a custom keyboard Application Extension named `TapKeys` to it.

Steps to reproduce:

1. From Xcode, run the custom keyboard target on device choosing any other app say Mail, tap on a text field to invoke regular keyboard.
2. At this point, switch to the Settings app. Add the custom keyboard.
   Back to Mail. Try switching to the custom keyboard.

This is what I see on the output pane:

```
TapKeys[1897:1008844] __27-[_UIRemoteKeyboards proxy]_block_invoke Failed to access remote service: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement.hosted was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement.hosted was invalidated.}
TapKeys[1897:1008844] XPC unexpectedly invalidated
```

What does this error mean and how do I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

This means that your keyboard needs a full-access.
To do that:

1. Open the info.plist from your Keyboard Target.
2. Set Value "Yes" for key "RequestsOpenAccess"
3. Run your App on your device
4. Go To Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Keyboards
5. Click on your keyboard
6. Set "Allow Full Access" True.